# How can i update composer in laravel 5.3

Tags: updates, laravel-5.3, composer-php

I had issue when i add code "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*" in composer.json, and then i try to update composer via command line in windows and show this in my command line.
PLEASE HELP ME GUYS, THANKS :))

[always show like this, if i try to update composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPVA8.png)

This my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: your composer.json does not contain valid json. post your composer.json code.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: Your composer.json file no longer has valid JSON. Post the contents of your composer.json file so we can debug further.

Comment: @alfa6661 please check my composer.json :)

Comment: @maiorano84 please chech my composer.json :)

Comment: missing comma in your composer.json, it should be `"laravel/framework": "5.3.*",`

Comment: @AjiPrasetyo, missing comma. check my answer below.

Comment: i try to add coma in "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",  and  i must delete coma in "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2" },

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a `comma(,)` here `"laravel/framework": "5.3.*",`

If invalid json error occurred you can check which line creates error by validating your json code [here](http://jsonlint.com/). Just paste your code and it will highlight the line(s) for you.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to change the line where it gives an error to something like this.

```
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
```

ANd to make it easier. Add a comma at the end of the

```
"laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: @AjiPrasetyo the comma? add it

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer :D

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.6.4",
            "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
            "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
            "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
            "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/TestCase.php"
            ]
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "php artisan key:generate"
            ],
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
                "php artisan optimize"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
                "php artisan optimize"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "preferred-install": "dist"
        }
    }
```

[Finally i can update composer :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0n3u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update your laravel/framework dependency to 5.3.* in your composer.json file.

You should also upgrade your symfony/css-selector and symfony/dom-crawler dependencies to 3.1.* in the require-dev section of your composer.json file.